# Preventing angularjs to add classes to form

Tags: angularjs, dropzone.js

I am trying to do something file uploading and using dropzone.js for this.
I have implemented the same without angularjs but with angular, I am facing some the dropzone form is not working.

Here the form :

```
<form class="dropzone" action="something" method="post" id="addImage">

      </form>
```

normally inspecting the page dropzone adds **dg-clickable** class to the form and some text. 
But with angular js it can't, instead angular adds ng-pristine and ng-valid to the form and then nothing happens.

How can I prevent angular from doing that?

Comment: have a look at this https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670

Comment: Yeah, its quite good

Answer (score 0):

excellent directive for dropzone: https://github.com/thatisuday/ngDropzone
here you have the demo: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/thatisuday/ngDropzone/blob/master/test/test.html

Comment: Didn't know about this one, but I have some looked upon some other dropzone directive, but can you please explain, why it isn't working normally and how to solve it?